# Use 'comma ok' idiom or return pointer?

Tags: go, idioms

Consider the following Go snippet:

```
func sheep() (int, bool) {
    return 1, true
}

func main() {
    if dolly, ok := sheep() {
         //do something
    }
}
```

As I read on ['Effective Go'](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) this is called the 'comma ok' idiom. As far as I can tell this is used to distinguish from a 'found' and 'not found' thing.

The same can be achieved via:

```
type Sheep struct {}

func sheep() *Sheep {
    return &Sheep{}
}

func main() {
    if dolly := sheep(); dolly != nil {
         //do something
    }
}
```

The latter example seems to fulfill the same purpose, perhaps even nicer. With the 'comma ok' example the assignment is only valid in the if block.

Perhaps I'm missing some considerations. Which pattern is preferred? And why?

A brief example: http://play.golang.org/p/ATxvle38iE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Go, a `nil` value may be a perfectly good value. For example a nil slice works (almost) like an empty slice, and the same may be true for user-defined pointer receivers.

For this reason, the comma-ok or comma-error idiom is usually preferred because it makes it obvious that the caller of the function needs to treat the error case (or the not-ok) case explicitly.

So, these are idiomatic when the `Sheep` return value may not be valid:

```
func sheep() (*Sheep, bool) {...}
func sheep() (s *Sheep, ok bool) {...}  // Adding names to make it clearer
func sheep() (*Sheep, error) {...}
```

And this is idiomatic only when the return value is always valid:

```
func sheep() *Sheep {...}
```

This is an area where Go is different from other languages, where a nil return value may be used to signal an error. The Go idioms of comma-ok and comma-error neatly work around the "billion-dollar mistake" of nil pointers by making code that doesn't deal with invalid return values look wrong. If you write idiomatic code, you can immediately see when errors are being ignored: for example the assignment to `s2` here immediately jumps out as suspicious:

```
s1 := sheep()
s2, _ := sheep()
```

Comment: What if there could be both - comma-ok and comma-error - value doesn't exist, or retrieval of value failed? I.e. getting an item from database can return no item for given unique key, or can fail due to I/O error.

Comment: @kravemir the usual solution is to return an error, then have some way of testing whether the error is because the key is not found" For example, `errors.Is(err, db.ExistError)`.

Comment: What about errors remapping then? In case, that DB layer returns `db.ErrNotExists`, the api/service/upper-layer should then check and remap it to `api.ErrNotExists`? Won't this lead to proliferation of error types? I doubt upper layers would be checking against `db.ErrNotExists` errors.

Comment: @kravemir You're right, you need to design apis carefully in a project so the user's not overwhelmed. One approach is to use a project-wide set of error types for common errors (like not-exist, permission failures, and so on) and then have your specific error types implement "Is" for them. For example, you can use errors in `fs` for this, and even if you have a custom error type you can make `errors.Is(myerr, fs.ErrNotExist)` return true. There's an example in: https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is

Comment: This is actually a good advice - either a valid value is returned, or error is present. With returning `ErrNotExist`, I don't have to do two checks - one for not found (`nil` pointer), and other one for error, in places where I expect a record to be retrieved - means found and fetched without any I/O errors. And, only in places where differentiation matters, I can check whether `errors.Is(err, ErrNotExist)`. Also error type check doesn't add that much code, when compared to `record != nil`, but it is more self-explanatory code, and I don't need to return pointers.

Answer (score 7):

Both are acceptable, plus you missed the most common idiom; Returning `value, error`.

The "comma ok" idiom as referenced in "Effective Go" is typically reserved for the builtin operations, like reading from a map or channel, and for type assertions.

I would use it if you need to return a value where a pointer would be unnecessary, inconvenient, or where nil is a valid value; but depending on the situation `value, error` could be just as good.

Comment: Why did they introduce "comma ok" in addition to "comma err"?  It looks like a missed opportunity of consistency, so I guess there's some good reason for that.